# How to get response data in error to swal message?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to get the message from json object `title` in the below response and show it in the swal message but cannot access this json response.

function from .ts file:

```
  addChangeWaveRequest(form: FormData) {

    const url = `${this.serverURL}/api/waveControl/add`;
    return this.http.post<FormData>(url, form, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'response',
    }).subscribe(responseData => {
      this.newUserStatus = responseData.ok;
      if (this.newUserStatus) {
        this.logService.info("User added Wave Update Successfully");
        Swal.fire(
          {
            icon: 'success',
            text: 'User added Wave Update Successfully'
          }
        );
        this.router.navigate(['/mediaList']);
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("error log:" + error);
      Swal.fire(
        {
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'There Is an Error Updaing Wave : ' + error
        }
      );
    });
    ;
  }
```

And I have this json in the response:

```
{
  "entityName" : "WaveService/addWaveChangeRequest",
  "type" : "https://www.ivrgui.com/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Please select both Arabic and English waves.",
  "status" : 400,
  "message" : "error.",
  "params" : "WaveService/addWaveChangeRequest"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot access this json response" ?

Comment: Which branch of your subscribe function is handling this response?

Comment: @ChrisBarr I mean I don't know how to read this data in error part

Comment: @James I copied this response from console tab in the browser, this response returns from '/api/waveControl/add' api in case of the error.

Comment: When your server returns this response does it get handled by the `responseData =>` func or the `error =>` func?

Comment: @James it should be handled by error func, but error result is [object, object]

Comment: Try adding `console.log(error)` to see what the actual object properties are.  You are getting `[object, object]` because you are trying to convert an entire object into a string.  If there is an `error.message` property (for example) then you should use that instead of the entire object: `'There Is an Error Updaing Wave : ' + error.message` (also you have a typo in "Updaing" - missing the "t"!)